# Running reveal.js in mdDialog or ngDialog

Tags: angularjs, reveal.js

Been trying to figure out a way to do this, and THINK I have figured out the issue, but have no clue what can be done.

Basically, I want a popup window to appear ala mdDialog or ngDialog, basically a nice window with loads of bits. But the issue is that if I do that, whatever is loaded in mdDialog or ngDialog as a template can only be HTML. It will not allow me to start reveal.js internally.

I have tried with both angular material and angular dialog. And both have the same issue.

Firstly, our very simple self contained reveal html.

```
<md-dialog aria-label="How to consume"  ng-cloak>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/reveal.js/css/reveal.css">
    <div>
        <div style="background-color: #00B700; height: 400px; width: 600px" class="reveal" >

            <div class="slides">
                <section><H1>This is one</H1></section>
                <section><H1>This is two</H1></section>
                <section><H1>This is three</H1></section>
                <section><H1>This is four</H1></section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/bower_components/reveal.js/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/reveal.js/js/reveal.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log("Trying to load now")
        Reveal.initialize({
            controls: true,
            progress: true,
            history: true,
            center: true,


            transition: 'slide', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom

            // Optional reveal.js plugins
            dependencies: [
                {
                    src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function () {
                    return !document.body.classList;
                }
                },
                {
                    src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function () {
                    return !!document.querySelector('[data-markdown]');
                }
                },
                {
                    src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function () {
                    return !!document.querySelector('[data-markdown]');
                }
                },
                {
                    src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/highlight/highlight.js',
                    async: true,
                    condition: function () {
                        return !!document.querySelector('pre code');
                    },
                    callback: function () {
                        hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
                    }
                },
                {src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true},
                {src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true}
            ]
        });
        Reveal.addEventListener('ready', function (event) {
            console.log("I have now entered " + event.currentSlide)
            // event.currentSlide, event.indexh, event.indexv
        });
    </script>
</md-dialog>
```

If you open that in a browser (and have reveal installed under bower_component) it works nicely.

If you open it in mdDialog or ndDialog nothing happens (it never fires the 
        } else if ( type === 'ngDialog') {
            console.log("Attempting to open ngDialog")
            ngDialog.open({ template: '/modals/consumer', controller: 'revealController'});

```
    } else if ( type === 'mdDialog') {
        $mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'revealController',
                templateUrl: '/modals/consumer',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                fullscreen: useFullScreen
            })
            .then(function (answer) {
                console.log('You said the information was "' + answer + '".');
                if(answer === 'login'){
                    $scope.external = false
                    $location.url('/int/index');
                }
            }
```

I also tried doing it via a controller, so same html using a controller as follows:

```
ngDialog.open({ template: '/modals/consumer', controller: 'displayRevealController'});
```

And trying to make a nice controller to call reveal:
Controller:

```
app.controller('displayRevealController', function($scope, $http, $mdDialog){
    console.log("I am so initialising")
    Reveal.initialize({
        controls: true,
        progress: true,
        history: true,
        center: true,


        transition: 'slide', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom

        // Optional reveal.js plugins
        dependencies: [
            {
                src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function () {
                return !document.body.classList;
            }
            },
            {
                src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function () {
                return !!document.querySelector('[data-markdown]');
            }
            },
            {
                src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function () {
                return !!document.querySelector('[data-markdown]');
            }
            },
            {
                src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/highlight/highlight.js',
                async: true,
                condition: function () {
                    return !!document.querySelector('pre code');
                },
                callback: function () {
                    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
                }
            },
            {src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true},
            {src: '/bower_components/reveal.js/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true}
        ]
    });
    Reveal.addEventListener('ready', function (event) {
        console.log("I have now entered " + event.currentSlide)
        // event.currentSlide, event.indexh, event.indexv
    });


});
```

But then I get an error message indicating that it cant find the DOM

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null